# Is there a way to compile Lisp source files in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: compilation, lisp, common-lisp

I want to write lisp code in Visual Studio Code and compile it on the terminal. Does anyone know if it's possible. If so, which command do I have to write?

Comment: FYI, if you're looking for a non-emacs editor, the SLIMA Atom extension is getting very good. https://github.com/CodyReichert/awesome-cl#text-editor-resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Medium article discussing that: [Getting Started With Common Lisp in 2018](https://medium.com/@bogomolnyelad/getting-started-with-common-lisp-in-2018-3a1b18c9050)

The section about VSCode gives a rudimentary workflow, namely open a terminal inside the editor, and call `Run Selected Text in Active Terminal` to execute the selected text. Then you can enrich your Lisp image snippet by snippet, or if you want a more reproducible approach, call `(compile-file ...)` on a script; ultimately, if you develop a library or an application, you better setup an [ASDF system](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/) and build it, possibly with [Quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/).